# Django regex in url patterns

Tags: regex, django

Is there any difference to use `[0-9]+` vs `d+` in `django` url patterns?
Any security difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "\d" in regex mean a digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479423/does-d-in-regex-mean-a-digit)

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107175/django-url-regex-with-variables) may be helpful for more information on django url patterns

Answer (score 3):

Django uses pythons `re` module, and from [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re):

> `\d` [...] Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many other digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is matched (but the flag affects the entire regular expression, so in such cases using an explicit [0-9] may be a better choice).

That is, this would also match e.g. arabic numbers. If you want that, then use `\d`, if not, then use `[0-9]`

Comment: Was about to write the same +1